# How to use public directory in Vite build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

In my project using Vite (`^2.9.7`) I have a `public` folder in my `root` directory which contains some images.

I'm importing the images using Vite's `import.meta.glob` function, e.g.

```
import { LazyBlock } from "../LazyBlock";

const images = import.meta.glob("./home/*.(jpg|png|jpeg)");

export function Gallery() {
  const blockImages = Object.keys(images);

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center w-full">
      <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center min-h-8">
        {blockImages.map((image, index) => (
          <LazyBlock url={image} key={index} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

While running in localhost, it works perfectly but there's an annoying warning saying to remove the `/public`:

```
files in the public directory are served at the root path.
Instead of /public/home/1.png, use /home/1.png.
```

But removing it, the images stop working.

But the main problem is when I build and deploy the project, the `public` folder stop existing and the route used stop working, but if change the src path in devtools, it simply works...

[image]

There's some configuration am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `Object.keys()` since it will always return the absolute path. Instead use `Object.values()`.

You can pass `{eager: true,import: 'default'}` for the second argument of the Glob Import, so that the return values will just be the public URL of the assets.

You code will look like this.

```
import { LazyBlock } from "../LazyBlock";

const images = import.meta.glob("./home/*.(jpg|png|jpeg)", {eager: true,import: 'default'});

export function Gallery() {
  const blockImages = Object.values(images);

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center w-full">
      <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center min-h-8">
        {blockImages.map((image, index) => (
          <LazyBlock url={image} key={index} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```